# boundary of the set {0, 1, 2} ∪ (0, 3) in R

Tags: real-analysis

I came up with an answer of (0,3]

I see that each epsilon neighborhood of x intersects A and R/A.
Does this logic work for this problem? It seems simple enough as both sets share 0,1,2 but not 3.

Comment: $
\{0,1,2\}\cup (0,3)=[0,3)
$.

Comment: Ah nice catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\{0,1,2\}\cup (0,3)=[0,3)$.

The closure of the set is $[0,3]$ and the interior is $(0,3)$, so the boundary is $\{0,3\}$